# How to get full string value of input type with jquery

Tags: jquery

Only first character i.e "{" is printed when I get the value set as value=" {"filename":"Image1.png","status":"SUCCESS"}

How can I get full string {"filename":"Image1.png","status":"SUCCESS"}

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(){
    var t = $(this).closest('.parentDiv').children("input[name='toFind']").val();
    console.log(t);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv" >
        <input type="hidden" name="toFind" value=" {"filename":"Image1.png","status":"SUCCESS"}">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="button" type="button" >Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That isn't valid markup. The quotes within the braces end your HTML, which means "     {" is the actual value of the input and the rest is just invalid. Escape your value.

Comment: FYI - Don't escape with backslashes, as one might assume from other languages, but use HTML entities to escape in your HTML attributes. `&quot;` is the HTML entity for quotes.

Comment: is this json printed from PHP or self JS ?

Comment: input tag is populated by javascript based on post response